# How to execute a scalar function in ssis expression?

Tags: sql, ssis

In my SSIS package, I need a variable with value `previous date`. To do that in SQL I have one scalar-valued function, which gives me `previous date`.

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, Fireball_Configuration.dbo.PreviousBusinessDay(),112)`

which returns me `PreviousBusinessDay`

How can I execute that scalar-valued function in SSIS for a variable? So that I can use that variable to my `file name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do..
Do you want to re-use the logic you build in SQL?
Or do you want to re-create the logic in SSIS?

You need to write some code in the script task to accomplish the later. 
For the first option: Use the Execute SQL Task. In the "General" tab select your Connection and your SQL Statement, something like SELECT PrevBusinessday = dbo.GetPreBusinessday(getdate()), Select Single row as ResultSet. Map the results to your Variable in the "Result Set" tab.